# Installing Pocketsphinx with pip on Windows 7

Tags: python, windows, pip, pocketsphinx

I'm trying to install pocketsphinx on Windows 7 for Python 2.7. I found this https://github.com/bambocher/pocketsphinx-python, installed the dependencies, ran pip install pocketsphinx, which resulted in the "Successfully installed pocketsphinx-0.0.5" message, but when I attempt to run python file which contains import pocketsphinx I get an import error, "no module named pocketsphinx." Any idea what the problem could be?

Comment: Try this, which is from the docs: `from pocketsphinx.pocketsphinx import *`

Comment: I had that in my code earlier, gives the same problem. "No module named pocketsphinx.pocketsphinx."

Answer (score 2):

**Windows Solution**

Christoph Gohlke kindly added a compiled version of pocketsphinx to his unofficial extension library.

If you are running Python 2.7 (32-bit) then download: "pocketsphinx-0.0.9-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl"

Here: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pocketsphinx

Then run: pip install "pocketsphinx-0.0.9-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl"

Answer (score 1):

The location you found is not well supported and has bugs. This particular one does not properly install `__init__.py`, that's why you can not load the module. I suggest you to build the official one instead, it should work:

http://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx-python